# left and right header background images overlapping when browser is resized

Tags: css, image, background, header

http://mooytees.net/ups-index.html

Resize the browser and you will see my problem: the images in the header overlap when the browser is made smaller. The MAIN issue is I am working in yahoo store editor (now aabaco small business) and have no access to the HTML to change it. I DO know that the id for the header is #header (duh), so I am working with that currently. The site works in templates which are written in RTML and I do not know how/am scared to change those. Please help!

Here is my CSS. I know it's hard with no HTML but there is not <strike>much</strike> anything I can do (at least, I don't think there is).

```css
#header{
background-color: #351e16;
background-image: url(http://site.mooytees.net/ups-header-left.png), url(http://site.mooytees.net/ups-header-right.png);
background-position: left top, right top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-width: 25%;

}

h3{
opacity:0;
height: 175px;
}

#header .searcharea{
display: none;
}
```

Comment: And what is the outcome you want? Smaller images? Hide images? Have them beneath each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by using a media query, I used the query to remove the "UPS" image, however you can use it as you see fit.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/4svoebdm/

**edit** here is an example with changing the size https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/4svoebdm/1/

```
@media (max-width: 800px){
 #header {
  background-image: url(http://site.mooytees.net/ups-header-right.png);
  background-position: left top;
} 
}
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks again for your help and the fast response! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a [`@media` query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/Media_queries) to apply specific styles on a smaller screen size.

Since the images in your example are background images, first add this property to `#header`

```
#header {
    background-size: contain;    
}
```

then, place a media query at the end of your file to make the header smaller on small screens

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #header {
        height: 100px !important;
    }
}
```